# Javascript to jquery conversion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to convert this javascript DOM into jquery, and my code isn't running for some reason. This is the DOM I am using.

```
document.getElementById("forma").onsubmit = function () {


  var ime = document.getElementById("ime").value;
    var priimek = document.getElementById("priimek").value;
    var stranka = document.getElementById("stranka").value;

    try {
        var kandidat = Kandidat(ime, priimek, stranka);
        DodajKandidataNaPolje(kandidat);
        document.getElementById("seznam").innerHTML = OblikujIzpis(PridobiPolje()); 
        document.getElementById("obvestila").innerHTML = "Uspešen Vnos!";
        document.getElementById("obvestila").className = "bg-success";
    }
    catch (napaka) {
        document.getElementById("obvestila").innerHTML = napaka.message;
        document.getElementById("obvestila").className = "bg-danger";
    }

    document.getElementById("forma").reset();    
}

document.getElementById("forma_isci").onsubmit = function () {
    var iskani_niz = document.getElementById("iskalniNiz").value;
    document.getElementById("seznam").innerHTML = OblikujIzpis(Isci(iskani_niz));
    document.getElementById("obvestila").innerHTML = "Rezultat iskanja po iskalnem nizu " + iskani_niz;
    document.getElementById("obvestila").className = "bg-info";
}

document.getElementById("pobrisi").onclick = function () {
    IzbrisiPolje();
    document.getElementById("obvestila").innerHTML = "Polje je bilo izbrisano!";
    document.getElementById("obvestila").className = "bg-success";
    document.getElementById("seznam").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("forma").reset();
}
```

This is what I tried writing in jquery.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("forma").submit(function(){
        var ime=$("ime").val();
        var priimek=$("priimek").val();
        var stranka=$("stranka").val();
        try{
        var kandidat= Kandidat(ime, priimek, stranka);
        DodajKandidataNaPolje(kandidat);
        $("seznam").html(OblikujIzpis(PridobiPolje());
        $("obvestila").html("Uspešen Vnos!");
        $("obvestila").addClass("bg-success");
    }
    catch(napaka){
        $("obvestila").html(napaka.message);
        $("obvestila").addClass("bg-danger");

    }

    $("forma").reset();

    $("forma_isci").submit=function(){
        var iskani_niz=$("iskaniNiz").val();
        $("seznam").html(OblikujIzpis(iskani_niz));
        $("obvestila").html("Rezultat iskanja po iskalnem nizu " + iskani_niz);
        $("obvestila").addClass("bg-info");
    }
    $("pobrisi".click=function(){
        IzbrisiPolje();
        $("obvestila").html("Polje je bilo izbrisano!");
        $("obvestila").addClass("bg-success");
        $("seznam").html("");
        $("forma").reset();
    }
    }
    });
});
</script>
```

here is my HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">    
    <script src="funkcije.js"></script>
    <script src="dom.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title>JavaScript - DOM</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <h1>Seznam predsedniških kandidatov!</h1>

      <form action="#" id="forma_isci" class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="iskalniNiz" placeholder="Iskalni niz">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Išči</button>
      </form>

      <br />
      <br />
      <h3>Vnos novih kandidatov</h3>
      <form action="#" id="forma" class="form-group">
        <table class="table">
          <tr>
            <td>Ime:</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" id="ime" placeholder="Ime kandidata" class="form-control"  /> 
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Priimek:</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" id="priimek" placeholder="Priimek kandidata" class="form-control"  /> 
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Stranka:</td>
            <td>
              <select id="stranka" class="form-control" >
                <option>Demokratska</option>
                <option>Republikanska</option>
                <option>Neodvisna</option>              
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input type="submit" value="Dodaj" class="btn btn-info" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="reset" value="Ponastavi" class="btn btn-info"  />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </form>

      <br />
      <br />
      <p id="obvestila"></p>

      <br />
      <br />
      <h3>Seznam obstoječih kandidatov</h3>
      <ul id="seznam" class="list"></ul>
      <button class="btn" id="pobrisi">Pobriši seznam</button>
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

So anyway, I'm not going to post the functions here since they're not needed to be seen here.

The javascript code works, the site works then and the elements get added normally. But I would like to have the same effect but written in Jquery. I think some of the issues are in .className, which I replaced with .Addclass from jquery and .innerHTML where I write .html(function). If someone could convert this for me it would be great, since I am kinda new to jquery I'm having some issues.

**update n1***

changed the Jquery to this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#forma").submit(function(){
        var ime=$("#ime").val();
        var priimek=$("#priimek").val();
        var stranka=$("#stranka").val();
        try{
        var kandidat= Kandidat(ime, priimek, stranka);
        DodajKandidataNaPolje(kandidat);
        $("#seznam").html(OblikujIzpis(PridobiPolje());
        $("#obvestila").html("Uspešen Vnos!");
        $("#obvestila").myClass("bg-success");
    }
    catch(napaka){
        $("#obvestila").html(napaka.message);
        $("#obvestila").myClass("bg-danger");

    }

    $("#forma").reset();
}
    $("#forma_isci").submit=function(){
        var iskani_niz=$("#iskaniNiz").val();
        $("#seznam").html(OblikujIzpis(iskani_niz));
        $("#obvestila").html("Rezultat iskanja po iskalnem nizu " + iskani_niz);
        $("#obvestila").myClass("bg-info");
    }
    $("#pobrisi".click=function(){
        IzbrisiPolje();
        $("#obvestila").html("Polje je bilo izbrisano!");
        $("#obvestila").myClass("bg-success");
        $("#seznam").html("");
        $("#forma").reset();
    }
    }
    });
});
</script>
```

Added the # where there's an ID, and changed .addClass to .myClass. Add function is still not working. But some other functions are working.

The functions.

```
var polje = [];

function Kandidat(ime, priimek, stranka) {
    if (ime ==="" || priimek === "") {
        throw new Error("Podatki niso popolni!");
    }
    else {
        var id = polje.length + 1;
        var oseba = {id:id, ime:ime, priimek:priimek, stranka:stranka};
        oseba.Izpis = function () {
        return "(" + this.id + ")" + this.ime + " " + this.priimek + " pripada stranki " + this.stranka;
    }
    return oseba;
    }


}

function DodajKandidataNaPolje(kandidat) {
    polje.push(kandidat);
    return true;
}

function PridobiPolje() {
    return polje;
}

function OblikujIzpis(polje) {
    var izpis = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < polje.length; i++) {
        izpis = izpis + "<li>" + polje[i].Izpis() + "</li>";
    }
    return izpis;
}

function Isci(iskalniNiz) {
    var rezultat = [];
    var oseba;
    var vsebuje;

    for (var i = 0; i < polje.length; i++) {
        oseba = polje[i];
        vsebuje = oseba.ime.search(iskalniNiz);
        if (vsebuje != -1) {
            rezultat.push(oseba);
        }
        else{
            vsebuje = oseba.priimek.search(iskalniNiz);
            if (vsebuje != -1) {
                rezultat.push(oseba);
            }
            else{
                vsebuje = oseba.stranka.search(iskalniNiz);
                if (vsebuje != -1) {
                    rezultat.push(oseba);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return rezultat;
}

function IzbrisiPolje() {
    polje = [];
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

in jQuery, in order to access an element, you need to use a selector.  In your case, the form has an id of `forma` (which in jQuery selectors, you prefix it with #). In order to access your form, you need to do the following:

change this:

```
$("forma").submit(function(){
```

to this:

```
$("#forma").submit(function(){
```

Anywhere else you use jQuery to access an element in your code would have to be changed as well.  use `#myid` for ids, `.myclass` for classes.  See [this](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for more information.

Here is your code (jQuery section only) with some things fixed:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var forma = $('#forma');

    forma.submit(function(){
        var ime=$("#ime").val();
        var priimek=$("#priimek").val();
        var stranka=$("#stranka").val();
        try{
            var kandidat= Kandidat(ime, priimek, stranka);
            DodajKandidataNaPolje(kandidat);
            $("#seznam").html(OblikujIzpis(PridobiPolje());
            $("#obvestila").html("Uspešen Vnos!");
            $("#obvestila").addClass("bg-success");
        } catch(napaka){
            $("#obvestila").html(napaka.message);
            $("#obvestila").addClass("bg-danger");

        }

        forma[0].reset();
    });

    $("#forma_isci").submit(function(){
        var iskani_niz=$("#iskaniNiz").val();
        $("#seznam").html(OblikujIzpis(iskani_niz));
        $("#obvestila").html("Rezultat iskanja po iskalnem nizu " + iskani_niz);
        $("#obvestila").addClass("bg-info");
    });

    $("#pobrisi").click(function( ){
        IzbrisiPolje();
        $("#obvestila").html("Polje je bilo izbrisano!");
        $("#obvestila").addClass("bg-success");
        $("#seznam").html("");
        forma[0].reset();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Sure. I can't fix everything.

Comment: Why not? Isn't that the question?

Comment: @ReneDrugiacc: I guess we'll make this wiki style via the comments. Switch `.myClass()` back to `.addClass()`. He meant that to select an element by class, you need `$(".someAwesomeClass")` *(note the `.`)*. These are all CSS style classes; it isn't unique to jQuery.

Comment: ...you have `$("#forma_isci").submit=function(){`, where `submit` should be a function call that passes the callback, so `$("#forma_isci").submit(function(){...})`

Comment: ...you also have `$("#pobrisi".click=function(){`, which is missing the closing parenthesis, and also should be a function call like in the above comment with `submit`.

Comment: ...finally, I don't believe jQuery has a `.reset()` method. I may be wrong since it's been years since I've used jQuery. IMO, you're better off keeping with your native DOM API instead of restricting yourself to an over-hyped external dependency.

Comment: Hmm my add function still isn't working,... the other ones are. Posted the functions in edited thread.